# Trouble Combining Two Data Frames R Studio

Tags: r, join

I want to combine these two dataframes in to one. I want to have the MCN_ID's stacked vertically and the UNS 1930 column to only be one column, not "UNS 1930.x" and "UNS 1930.y" which is what my code is currently resulting in. This is ultimately being done a large scale with multiple loops for this merge. Please help!

```
test1 <- data.frame("AABB", 1)
colnames(test1)[1] <- "MCN_ID"
colnames(test1)[2] <- "UNS 1930"

test2 <- data.frame("BBAA", 23)
colnames(test2)[1] <- "MCN_ID"
colnames(test2)[2] <- "UNS 1930"

test3 <- full_join(test1, test2, by = "MCN_ID")
```

Gives this result:

```
MCN_ID   UNS 1930.x   UNS 1930.y
AABB     1            NA  
BBAA     NA           23
```

But I want this:

```
MCN_ID   UNS 1930
AABB     1  
BBAA     23
```

Comment: You need `rbind` or `bind_rows(test1, test2)` instead of join

Comment: Try using `?merge` and choosing by.x and by.y as the colnames you want

Comment: FYI, `colnames(test1) <- c("MCN_ID", "UNS 1930")`. Perhaps even `test1 <- data.frame(MCN_ID="AABB", "UNS 1930"=1, check.names=FALSE)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R - Concatenate two dataframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169323/r-concatenate-two-dataframes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bind_rows from dplyr. This will work even with columns out of order which is a nice extra vs rbind:

```
library(dplyr)
testout <- bind_rows(test1,test2)

> testout
  MCN_ID UNS 1930
1   AABB        1
2   BBAA       23
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! This was just a simple example of a more complicated process and this is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much.

Comment: Okay so I am running multiple for loops through multiple dataframes and it comes out like this: (type this into your R to see the output) `testdf <- data.frame(c("AABB", "AABB","AABB","AACC","AACC","AACC","AADD","AADD","AADD"),c(0,"NA","NA",1,"NA","NA",1,"NA","NA"),c("NA",0,"NA","NA",1,"NA","NA",2,"NA"),c("NA","NA",0,"NA","NA",1,"NA","NA",2))`

Instead, I want it to be (type this in) `testdf <- data.frame(c("AABB","AACC","AADD"),c(0,1,1),c(0,1,2),c(0,1,2))` so that there are no duplicates and everything is found in the same row

Comment: Further Update: I added the following line to my code `Result_df <- Result_df %>%
      group_by(MCN_ID) %>%
      summarise_each(funs(first(na.omit(.))))` which seemed to do the trick

Comment: Just as a note, the way you created your tables you factorized them. Add ```stringsAsFactors=FALSE``` to keep as strings and numeric in the ```testdf <- data.frame() ```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use: `test3 <- rbind(test1, test2)`