# Combining two dataframes using R

Tags: r

Sorry I could not find similar questions here.

I am trying to combine two data frames,

```
a <- c(a, b, c, d)
b <- c(x, y, z)
```

`result` should be

```
result <- c(a,b,c,d,x,y,z)
```

I have tried `paste`, it did not work.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169323/r-concatenate-two-dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
union(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), c('x', 'y', 'z'))
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "x" "y" "z"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `c` to concatenate two vectors

```
c(a, b)
```